# How do you delete an Unpublished or Removed app from the Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

I would like to completely delete an application from the Google Play Store through the Google Play developer console. The app is currently unpublished, but I am unable to delete it.

I would like to delete the app so that I cannot even see it in my developer console, but I have no idea how to do that.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have found out that deleting Android apps are not possible, only unpublishing. [That according to Google's support site.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055196?hl=en#ts=3056520)